# Creating home directory using createhomedir command not working in swift script but works manually in terminal

Tags: swift, xcode, bash

I have a swiftui script that takes user input via swiftUI gui components (username, password) and then creates a user account on the macos system that the script is being run on, using the dscl and createhomedir commands. All of the dscl commands work e.g. creating the user, setting the password for the user, setting UID and GID etc. However, when it comes to creating the user's home directory inside /Users/, the createhomedir command doesn't actually create the directory even though there are no errors captured from the process output and the output message is actually the same successful output message you get when running the command in the terminal by hand. The project's scheme is edited to run as root and all the other root required commands run successfully. The following code is supposed to create the home directory for the user:

```
func createHomeDirectory(username: String) -> Bool {
    var success = true
    if self.isSaneUserName(username: username) {
        print("user name is valid and is \(username)")
        let task = Process()
        let outputPipe = Pipe()
        let errorPipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = outputPipe
        task.standardError = errorPipe
        task.launchPath = "/usr/sbin/createhomedir"
        task.arguments = ["-c", "-u", username]
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
        print("home directory created.")
        let errorOutput = errorPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let errorString = String(decoding: errorOutput, as: UTF8.self)
        if errorString != "" {
            print("error string: \(errorString)")
            print("There was an error running the create home directory command")
            success = false
        }
        let ouput = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let outputString = String(decoding: ouput, as: UTF8.self)
        if outputString != "" {
            print("output string: \(outputString)")
        }
    }
    return success
}
```

The output of the command purports success however the home directory isn't created. And when running this same command `/usr/sbin/createhomedir -c -u username` in the terminal, it creates the home dir no problem. I know I can do a mkdir command but running the createhomedir command

1. should work either way
2. is supposed to apply the correct ownership to the directory outright without having to run additional chown commands

I'm thinking this is an issue with possibly running the script in xcode. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the exit status to know it worked

```
let status = task.terminationStatus
 
if status == 0 {
    print("Task succeeded.")
} else {
    print("Task failed.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I put your code in and as I expected, the output was:
`user name is valid and is *redacted*`
`Task succeeded.`
`home directory created.`
`output string: creating home directories for (*redacted*)`

Comment: So it is created then

Comment: No it doesn't get created. MacOs isn't always accurate with their return codes. The code is still failing to create the home directory even after the termination status returns 0.